# When I resize my Form to full screen my controls are still on old position

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
```

What code I can applied on `picturebox2` so that `picturebox2` also displaced according to form ...

Comment: I don't see a picturebox2 in this code? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes am asking About about the that What i can do with picture box2 ???
Picture box1 covers my whole form and picture box2 is small picture on it ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of the controls to determine their behavior when the form is resized. 
When using docks and anchors in WinForms, you typically decide for a primary control (group) that gets the main part of the screen and another group of controls that are aligned in the remaining area. So if you set DockStyle.Fill for PictureBox1 control, you set the other PictureBox to DockStyle.Right. When the form is resized, the main area is extended. Please note however, that it sometimes depends on the order that the controls were created on how they are aligned and whether it works as expected. It might take some experimenting with putting various controls to foreground in order to reach your goal.
This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty26a068%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) lists a lot of tutorials on how to align controls on Windows Forms, specifically on setting [anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) controls.
In addition, you can use various layout controls, among them a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Thanks @HansPassant for the hint). For a walk-through see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I am using Anchor as Top,Bottom,Left,Right but it stretch my control so control looks very big ... its not in Ratio ...

Comment: @Satinder: extended my answer.

Comment: He wants a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for solving the puzzle. Looks exactly like it.

Comment: @Satinder: Have a look at the TableLayoutPanel as Hans Passant pointed out. I've added some links to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set anchors to all your controls on your form( by default all your controls are "tied" to the top and left of your form) . If anchors are not enough try using dock panels and dock your control.

You can se the anchors from the visual editor. Select a control and on the properties panel you should set the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to scale the child controls as the main window is scaled.
try the Scale method by calculating of the scale factor as below:

**the code:**

```
Size st = this.Size;
        int height = st.Height;
        int width = st.Width;

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

        Size newSize = this.Size;

        SizeF scaleFactor = new SizeF();
        scaleFactor.Height = newSize.Height / height;
        scaleFactor.Width = newSize.Width / width;

        this.Scale(scaleFactor);
```

Comment: But its not working for the Child Control like 
picturebox2.Scale(scaleFactor);

Comment: set the scale factor for the Form. this should also scale all the child controls(which includes the picture box).If image within the Picture box is not scaled then Change the "**PictureBox.SizeMode**" property to "**StretchImage**".

Comment: if pictureBox2 is not displayed because it is in back, try using pictureBox2.BringToFront();